# Split text into smaller parts identified by needle

Tags: php, split

I want to split a string like this one :

```
'This <p>is</p> a <p>string</p>'
```

I want to get 4 strings :

- This
- `<p>is</p>`
- a
- `<p>string</p>`

So I want to find `<p></p>` and its content one by one to split it. How can I do it keeping the same sequence ?

I can get 'This' with that code : `$html1 = strstr($html, '<p', true);` but I don't know how to continue splitting and how to do it for variable strings with many needles (at least 2 different needles). Can you help me with it ?

Comment: Is it true only for `p` tags?

Comment: if you just want your `p` tag, you can split your string using a REGEX capturing `<p> * </p>`

Comment: I suggest you come up with some rule that can be implemented with regular expressions using capturing groups.

Comment: For parsing HTML strings, you might want to consider [converting to a DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) and using PHP's built in tools.

Comment: Aren't just just splitting on whitespace? https://3v4l.org/afmZt

Comment: If you are dealing with such plain strings (it wouldn't get more HTML) try `$nodes = preg_split('~(<p>.*?</p>)~', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);`

Comment: After the first strstr which gives me 'This', I want to get `<p>is</p>` so I think strstr should not be true and actually, I'm not 100% sure I can get what I want with `strstr`

Comment: You can do it the hard way, with `substr()` or you can do it the easy way, with `preg_match()` or a real HTML parser. The question is: do you want to identify only the `<p>...</p>` block or there are also other HTML elements you are interested in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with some options (`$s` is the input string):

```
preg_split("#\s*(<p>.*?</p>)\s*#", $s, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

This returns an array. For your sample input it returns:

```
["This", "<p>is</p>", "a", "<p>string</p>"]
```

See it run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/IjxB/1)

Comment: This is a great solution. Didn't know that `preg_split` was this powerful. Note you don't need to escape `/` since you use `#` as the regex end-brackets.

Comment: Thanks, @BeetleJuice. Removed the escape.

Answer (score 0):

Because your needles are complex, you could use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$html = 'This <p>is</p> a <p>string</p>';

// Regex to group by paragraph and non-paragraph
$pattern = '/(.*?)(<p>.+?<\/p>)/';

// Parse HTML using the pattern and put result in $matches
preg_match_all($pattern,$html,$matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

// Will contain the final pieces
$pieces = [];

// For each $match array, the 0th member is the full match
// every other member is one of the pieces we want
foreach($matches as $m) while(next($m)) $pieces[] = trim(current($m));

print_r($pieces);// ['This', '<p>is</p>', 'a', '<p>string</p>']
```

[**Live demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/991a47e68552d1847f7ab9f3142ec41a74dc26c4)